# How to join multiple files in two directories in powershell?

Tags: file, powershell, merge

I have 2 folders OldData and NewData. In both folders I have a thousands of csv files with the  same names. Looking for a most effective way how to merge files with the same names from both folders and store them in NewData folder.

Example:

```
OldData folder:
test1.csv
test2.csv
.
.
```

NewData folder:

```
test1.csv (same names than in OldData folders but not exactly the same content)
test2.csv
.
.
```

In NewData folder there should be merged files from both folders. Files in OldData folder have header. Files in new data folder are without header, but they have same structure(same number of columns).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Do the csv files have a header row?

Comment: Files in OldData folder have header. Files in new data folder are without header, but they have same structure(same number of columns).

Comment: Edited the question as that is very important information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\OldData\*.csv' | % {
  $dst = Join-Path 'C:\NewData' $_.Name
  Import-Csv $_.FullName | Export-Csv $dst -Append
}
```

**Edit:** If the files in OldData do have headers while the files in NewData don't, I'd append the new files to the old ones, not the other way around.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\NewData\*.csv' | % {
  $dst = Join-Path 'C:\OldData' $_.Name
  if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $dst) {
    Get-Content $_.FullName | Add-Content $dst
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've tried your code, but it doesn't do anything. There is no error, just it didn't append data.

Comment: Try just the `Import-Csv | Export-Csv` with a single file and explicit paths. Does that work or do you get an error? Do both files have the same columns in the same order, and do they contain a header row, as mjolinor asked? My sample code assumes that both applies. Also, which PowerShell version do you use? `Export-Csv` doesn't support `-Append` prior to version 3.

Comment: It doesn't work for single file either. I'm using version 4.Files in OldData folder have header. Files in new data folder are without header, but they have same structure(same number of columns)

Comment: Works fine. Only one problem. I don't want to create a new file if in OldData folder file doesn't exist. So if in a NewData folder is file with name test10.csv and in OldData the file test10.csv is missing. I don't want to create a new file.

Comment: Then just check if the destination file exists.